# Why suddenly a thread runs ONE portion of a method?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm really stuck at something and this place is the only one I can get an answer. I beg you to read it from the start till the end.

I have a method does something like this below:

```
public void Execute(Data data)
{
    bool IsOk = false;
    //1st point
    IsOk = Check1();

    //2nd point
    if(IsOk)
      IsOk = Check2();

    //3nd point
    if(IsOk)
      IsOk = Check3();

    //4th point
    if(IsOk)
       SendMessage();

}
```

The data object is get by a `STATIC` method in order to prevent more than 1 thread accessing it as below:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public static DataCollection GetDataColl()
{
   //By syncronizing, I'm guaranteeing every data is unique.
   DataCollection Result = new DataCollection();
   Result = GetDataFromDatabase();//Changing status in order to prevent getting it again
   return Result;
}
```

And after this, I give the method below to the `THREADS` to process the `DataCollection`:

```
//When invoked, creates the threads that runs my actual processing method
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for(int i= 1; i <= 2; i++ )
   {
      Thread ProcessThread = new Thread(ProcessData);
      ProcessThread.Start();
   }
}

//Process the data
private void ProcessData()
{
   DataCollection Coll = GetDataColl(); //GetDataColl is static, threadsafe that can be invoked only by 1 thread at a time method.

   //Foreach through data and execute the PROBLEMATIC method "Execute" at the beginning
   foreach(Data dta in Coll)
      Execute(dta); //The problem occurs in this method
}
```

The problem occurs time to time, not always but you could give it about 20% at the time which is more than enough I suppose. Here is what happens:

1. `Thread 1`: Runs 1st point of Execute method
2. `Thread 1`: Runs 2nd point of Execute method
3. `Thread 1`: Runs 3rd point of Execute method
4. `Thread 2`: Runs 4th point of Execute method -> Wierd!
5. `Thread 1`: Runs  4th point of Execute method

Out of the blue, in the **middle** of the method, this new thread comes RIGHT AT THIS POINT and executes a portion of the whole method. This new thread (`Thread 2`) does **NOT** even goes to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd point at all)

Sometimes it happens in this order as well:

1. `Thread 1`: Runs 1st point of Execute method
2. `Thread 1`: Runs 2nd point of Execute method
3. `Thread 2`: Runs 4th point of Execute method -> Weird!
4. `Thread 1`: Runs 3rd point of Execute method.
5. `Thread 1`: Runs 4th point of Execute method.

All these are read and written here from the log file, not by **debugging**. When I do the debug, everything seems fine.

I used log4net and here is simplified sample of what happened:

```
2013-02-19 09:53:02,057 [39] DataId: 4356502 - Check1
2013-02-19 09:53:02,088 [39] DataId: 4356502 - Check2
2013-02-19 09:53:02,088 [39] DataId: 4356502 - Check3
2013-02-19 09:53:02,542 [39] DataId: 4356502 - Send
2013-02-19 09:53:02,573 [46] DataId: 4356502 - Send
```

Thread No 46 did not even went for Check 1,2,3 at all.

Comment: Well that's the point of threads. It does some stuff, the OS stop it and switches to another thread, that thread runs for a little while and is then preempted by the OS who picks another thread to run. It seems you want cooperative threads instead of preemtive threads. The synchronization you have is _only_ on the `GetDataColl` call, not in the thread in general.

Comment: Have you tried swapping out `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` for `lock` inside the method? Also, try it without the static. I know it seems like grasping at straws but would be interesting to see if it changes anything.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg surely it shouldn't switch the job to another thread though? I can understand if it went thread1 job1, thread1 job2, thread2 job1, thread1 job3 - but just straight to the end of a method?

Comment: One thing that makes this _very_ hard to answer, is that you post code that "does something like this". It very hard to answer when we don't have all information. If possible please make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Try logging to the console instead.

Comment: I'll try to prepare a sample working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have soled the problem in here,

When the main thread start, it uses a STATIC variable that holds the singleton Message Collection. Since, other threads tries to run over this singleton collection, the main thread momentarily changes the value (which is clearly my mistake and I solved it by cloning the updated object) and resulting other threads using this modified object when they should have the original value.

This situation looked like a problem that I asked as a question.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code, albeit a little changed, and it appears to work fine. Check higher up the output, make sure that thread [46] didn't execute before the thread [39] before being put on hold.

```
th1 - Check 1 example string 235236
th1 - Check 2 example string 235236 <- thread1 gets to #2 and stops
th2 - Check 1 example string 235236
th2 - Check 2 example string 235236
th2 - Check 3 example string 235236 <- thread2 gets to #3
th1 - Check 3 example string 235236 <- thread1 starts up again, at #3
th2 - Check 4 example string 235236 <- thread4 then finishes off with #4
th2 - Check 1 example string 135236
th2 - Check 2 example string 135236
th2 - Check 3 example string 135236
th1 - Check 4 example string 235236 <- thread1 appears and finishes #4
th2 - Check 4 example string 135236
```

Comment: THank you Adam. I'm currently working on a very simplified version of my original project which I hope to create the same conditions. Hope to do it within the hour and I'll share it here.

Comment: Let me know when you have and I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok. I'll send a link in a zip. I currently completed, but for some reason 1 thread always works with that method until it finishes. I'll send as a link the moment I got this right (or wrong in this case :) )

Comment: I think I've found the problem, but I'will not be able to fully test it untill tomorrow morning at 10:00 A.M. But if I'M right, the answer will be a whole different era for me. I'Ll post the answer tomorrow.

Comment: Adam, I didnt have the time to write my answer down until now. I thank you again for the help.